# The messages page on Careers gives a 404

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

When I go to check my [messages](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/messages) on Stack Overflow Careers I get a 404 page rather than an empty inbox.

[image: 404'd]

Comment: I can't reproduce it.  Mine shows up just fine.

Comment: @Pollyana, do you actually have a CV?

Comment: what do you see when you go to "my profile" -- are you an active candidate (can edit your profile) or a passive (cannot edit)?

Comment: @David, I see the request a profile page. (How do I get one/Request immediate invite). So if I don't have either, I'm guessing I shouldn't even be able to see the messages link?

Comment: yep, something has gone horribly wrong :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We were sometimes showing the "messages" link for users who do not have a profile yet, and so can't have any messages.  This has been fixed.

Comment: i am also getting 404 on message page now