# Email Verification on careers went to wrong email

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

Originally, when I signed up for an openid account to access SO, I used one email address - my work email.  Much later, I associated a personal email with my account, and removed my work email.

Yesterday, I received an email verification email from careers to my work email, and I'm not sure why this is, given that I no longer see that email anywhere attached to my SO account (or on the openid account by itself).

Obviously, the solution for **me** is to just change the email on the careers account - I post because I'm curious why this occurred at all, as it looks like a bug.

Comment: It could be that the e-mail was **sent** when you had your work address set but wasn't **received** until after you'd change it. E-mail isn't instantaneous. Then as far as Careers was concerned it was sending to the right address.

Comment: A fair point; since I neglected to specify, I changed the email probably over a **year** ago, and I only received a careers invitation **yesterday**.

Comment: Unless the e-mail was **really** slow that's unlikely to be the reason then ;)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the report and really sorry about that.  We actually created a mini careers profile for you under our [Passive Search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80254/new-careers-feature-passive-candidate-search-feedback-wanted) program almost a year ago, before you changed your e-mail on your Stack Overflow account.  What we didn't do was update your careers e-mail when you changed it on Stack Overflow. Hence we sent your verification e-mail to your very old and very wrong address.

Definitely a bug.  I'm working on a fix now.

Comment: Wait a second - are you saying that you make profiles for us without telling us?  Why not tell us about them?

Comment: @Nate: Yes. The "profile" we create here is simply public data from your Stack Overflow profile that anyone could read.  We don't expose any of your private information and we tightly control the messaging system.  If any employer ever wants to send you a message when you're in this state, you then get to opt in to further communication.

Comment: Ah. Well, that's a little different.  BTW, I also noticed the same was true with other info - not just the email (e.g., gravatar).  Also, when I edited my email, a new confirmation was not sent to my new email address.  Was this by design?

Comment: @Nate: Gravatar works by hashing your email address, so it should have updated when you updated your email address.